# Which files of addressable assets should be committed to Git?

Tags: unity, assets, git

I would like to keep my Git repository as small as possible and exclude any automatically generated files. The developers can re-build their Unity Addressable Assets themselves. Any developer should be able to build the final project and the final result should contain the same assets packed in the same way.

I noticed that Unity generates the following files and folders:

[image]

Which of these files are important settings that should be included and which files are safe to exclude from a Git repository?

Comment: I think this should contain great advices: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-git-with-unity

Comment: @Andrea Thanks, but that article was written in 2017 before Addressables existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It broke when I removed any of these:

```
/AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroups
/AddressableAssetsData/DataBuilders
```

Nothing broke (no obvious errors) when I removed

```
/AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroups/Schemas
/AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroupTemplates
```

... but when I build the application, the Addressables were missing and after further investigation I noticed that each Group's Content Packing & Loading "Component" (actually "Schema") was obviously missing so I assume Unity just silently ignored the packing of my assets.  And without the AssetGroupTemplates, my AddressableAssetSettings asset showed that the Asset Group Templates were missing, so I guess that is also a required folder.

The following addition to the .gitignore will only remove the binaries generated by the Asset packing and keep all the other settings.

```
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*
```